# getting no permissions added in OAuth 2.0 scopes while creating app in linkedin developer

Tags: oauth-2.0, permissions, linkedin-api, access-token

There are no permission added while creating app on linkedin developer account. I just want to learn how to use linked-api in production.
Thank you

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBwg4.jpg

Comment: Thanks its work now. I want to fetch latest post,like and comments. How to do this. When I am using this url call https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people/(id:{person ID}) getting 403 error Not enough permissions to access: GET /people/id  (I am passing my own id which I got from https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me) here

Answer (score 9, accepted):

from the app settings page go to the product tab and add Share on linkedin and Signin with linkedin to get the following permissions r_emailaddress, r_liteprofile, w_member_social